# Asynchronous Encryption with wordlists

Tags: encryption

As I understand it encrypted emails have a high profile (detectable through pgp header / attachment).

Would it be possible to match the encrypted data with a wordlist to hide the fact that the email contains a encrypted message?

I know that the other person would need the same list of words for decrypting and the message would be only a bunch of random words, but the fact that its encrypted world be not as obvious for automated scanning.

EDIT: As pointed out I am referring to steganography to hide from traffic analysis.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "steganography to hide from traffic analysis". Traffic analysis means taking note of who's talking to whom. It doesn't matter if I send you plaintext emails, encrypted emails, steganography or just pictures of kittens: traffic analysis will still say "David just started sending mails to Xenira."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  It is called [steganography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography) and there are many techniques that can be used -- there is an entire literature on the subject.  You might enjoy reading about it.

It still won't stop [traffic analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_analysis).